# how to upgrade HTC hero from os 1.5 to 2.1?

Tags: android

i have HTC hero phone with operating system 1.5 
i want to upgrade it to version 2.1 can any one guide me the complete procedure ?

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so this isn't the place to ask to it I'm afraid.  Try http://www.forceclose.com - the Stack Exchange site for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php/Main_Page) is the only way to go. I modded mine and it works great. There is an unofficial mod specific to the Hero [here](http://android.modaco.com/content/htc-hero-hero-modaco-com/301857/cyanogenmod-for-htc-hero-gsm-v1-0-now-with-online-kitchen/)

Comment: when official os is going to launch do you have any idea?

Comment: Should be a few weeks, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The official Android 2.1 rom is out now. Make sure your phone is clean by downloading the original rom from the HTC website. Then, you will receive the new rom automatically.